# Unlocking original casement window for house built in 1938

Tags: windows

I have the key to unlock this window but I cannot figure out how to get it to open.

I believe you need to not turn the key but I cannot remember.

[image]

Comment: That lock is not "original" equipment, it was added sometime in recent decades. The reference to the age of the window and mention of "original" is thus an unneeded red herring.

Comment: Hi Susan, this question is unclear/needs more detail. First, it seems obvious that the lock cylinder needs to be rotated so it isn't 'caught' by the second/top half... so why do you think you need to "not" turn the key in order to open the window? Second, have you tried anything yet? Third, and piggybacking off #2, have you unscrewed the screws to see if it opens fine without the lock in place?

Answer (score 1):

It might need lubrication, depending hw long it's sat locked.

If your belief is correct then you'd insert the key and rotate the handle from left to right (anti-clockwise.) That certainly seems plausible given how small the whole thing is - the lock cylinder also being the whole rotating mechanism, rather than having two separate interacting rotating parts.